# How to parse \n in a custom cli

Tags: c, shell, backslash

I've written code for a [shell](http://github.com/montao/opsh) that we call opsh (the OPen SHell).

Now my friend found an [issue](https://github.com/montao/opsh/issues/37) about backslash preceeded characters that don't behave as expected.

Example

> opsh does not seem to pass on the -character to echo.

In opsh:

```
$
$echo "TEXT\n"
TEXTn
$
whereas in ksh:
$
$echo "TEXT\n"
TEXT
```

I don't know how to do it. In my code I just use a pipeline for the commands (you may look at the entire code in the repo) where the relevant code looks as follows

```
int run_cmd(char *cmd, bool background) {

    char buffer[2];
    buffer[0] = '|';
    buffer[1] = '\0';
    struct str_list *chunks = list_split(cmd, buffer);
    struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);
    if (pipe == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < chunks->pipes; i++) {
        pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char **) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
        if (pipe[i].data == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
        }
        int j = 0;
        pipe[i].size = chunks[i].size;
        for (j = 0; j < chunks[i].size; j++) {
            if (chunks[i].argv[j] == NULL) {
                chunks[i].argv[j] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            pipe[i].option = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
            if (pipe[i].option == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
            }
            pipe[i].data[j] = strdup(chunks[i].argv[j]);
            if (pipe[i].data[j] == NULL) {
                perror("strdup");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            * pipe[i].option = * chunks[i].option;
        }
        pipe[i].data[j] = '\0';
    }
    int status = execute_pipeline(chunks->pipes, pipe, background);
    return status;
}


int execute_pipeline(int n, struct pipeline *pipe, bool background) {
    // background = false;
    int status = 0;
    pid_t pid = -2;
    if (n > -1)
        pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }
    /* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* spawn(cmd);*/
        fork_pipeline(n, pipe);
    }
    /*
     * We are the parent process.
     * Wait for the child to complete.
     */

    if (!background) {
        while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: executed\n", (int) pid);
    }
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

        return -1;
    }
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}


/* Helper function that forks pipes */
void fork_pipeline(int n, struct pipeline *structpipeline) {
    int i;
    int in = 0;
    int fd[2];
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
            err_syserr("Failed creating pipe");
        }
        spawn_pipe(in, fd[1], structpipeline + i);
        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }
    if (dup2(in, 0) < 0) {
        err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", structpipeline[i].data[0]);
    }

    if (strstr(structpipeline[i].data[0], "=")) {
        /* do nothing for now, handle in parser instead... */
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int) getpid(), structpipeline[i].data[0]);
        //fprintf(stderr, "\n");

        if (* (structpipeline[i].option) == 1) { /* output redirection */
            int length = structpipeline[i].size;
            char *filename = structpipeline->data[length - 1];
            for (int k = length - 2; k < length; k++)
                structpipeline->data[k] = '\0';

            fd[1] = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
        } /* TODO: input redirection */
        execvp(structpipeline[i].data[0], structpipeline[i].data);
        err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", structpipeline[i].data[0]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Many shells, including `ksh`, have their own built-in version of `echo`, which is normally more featureful than the standalone implementation.

Comment: @kdhp Cool. My intention with my shell is to create a rescue shell that is a little more featureful than sash (which almost can't do anything) and do very good basic functionality. You may have a look at my built-ins if you like to vire `do.h` in the repo. I'll definitely try and make a built-in version of `echo` and also some more built-ins that can be needed in a rescue / recovery situation where one must recover the installation and can't use system commands because the system crashed.

Comment: `echo` binary (/bin/echo) doesn't recognize escape sequences. Unless you specify `-e` flag. Try `echo -e "test\n"`

Comment: @aragaer Note that `echo` accepting any options, other than `-n`, is non-standard behavior.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/echo-invocation.html says that `-n`, `-e` and `-E` are standard.

Comment: @aragaer From that manual: "POSIX does not require support for any options"

Comment: I suppose then I can just add the `-e` switch in my shell internal if the command is detected as being `echo` if I want the functionality of echoing newline like that. Do you agree?

Comment: @DjDac BSD `/bin/echo` is POSIX complaint, meaning that `echo -e '\n'` results in the line `-e \n`.

Comment: @DjDac The issue linked is correct in that the processing of a`"` quoted string is not preserving the ```\``` . The ```\``` is suppose to be preserved when not used to escape a `$`, `\``, `"`, ```\``` , or newline. Ex. `printf "\n\\n"` results a line with a single `n` character, not two line-feeds.